# Does Flutter have a way around Android's size limit on Emojis?

Tags: android, flutter, emoji

Android still seems to scale emojis in a Bizzar way.

I've seen that this is an issue in other Android development platoforms, up to Android 11, and it still seems to exist now in Android 12.
[Android discussion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVUJc.png)

Perhaps Flutter has some way around it? Like a zoom function, or convert to an image before scaling or something?
InteractiveViewer doesn't work (if anything, wrapping the column widget with InteractiveViewer is a great way to demonstrate the actual issue).

I use a Fitted box to scale up an Emoji in Flutter to whatever the size is in a parent container. It works just fine on most platforms, however, in Android, going above about 90px does weird things to the final render.

This is what it looks like in dart-pad:

[image: DartPad example]

And now in Android (either real phone, or the emulator): you can clearly see a scaling issue. The large yellow curve is the emoji that is supposed to be 90x90:

[edit] On the emulator, there is no large yellow curve, but the emojis are still missing.

[image: Android screenshot]

Here is the code to try yourself.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const String emoji = "";
    return InteractiveViewer(
      child: Column(children: [
        Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            width: 70,
            height: 70,
            child: const FittedBox(fit: BoxFit.contain, child: Text(emoji))),
        Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            width: 80,
            height: 80,
            child: const FittedBox(fit: BoxFit.contain, child: Text(emoji))),
        Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: 90,
            height: 90,
            child: const FittedBox(fit: BoxFit.contain, child: Text(emoji))),
        Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: const FittedBox(fit: BoxFit.contain, child: Text(emoji))),
        Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: 180,
            height: 180,
            child: const FittedBox(fit: BoxFit.contain, child: Text(emoji))),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

[EDIT] @Marcel Dz is onto something in their comment "try your code using flutter version 2.10.5" ... The investigation continues.

[image]

Comment: can you please do me a favor and try your code using flutter version 2.10.5 ? if it works ill add additional information about the behaviour

Comment: @MarcelDz You are onto something... see the update in the question.

Comment: @MarcelDz https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: hey sorry not responding yet, seems like the rendering is fine there

Comment: I wouldn't really call that "fine". Its very blurry.

Comment: Your code is working fine with Flutter 3.3.8. If you are still facing the issue, add fontSize inside TextStyle !